# tuning linux cache settings for inode caching

Tags: linux, cache, inode

I am dealing with hundred million files in a filesystem (distributed among a lot of subdirectories), and I need to be able to list them very quickly, particularly in order to rsync them efficiently.

On a other hand, I don't really need to have the actual content of the file kept in cache.

I am constantly adding and removing files, but not that frequently (something like ten times per second).

Is there a way I can tell the OS (2.6.18-194.el5) to use the 24GB available RAM more on inode caching than on file caching? I already looked at /proc/etc/vm/vfs_cache_pressure but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I am looking for...

Answer (score 6):

How about lowering the value for `vfs_cache_pressure`?
According to [Documentation for /proc/sys/vm/*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) this should do what you want:

> ### vfs_cache_pressure
>
> This percentage value controls the tendency of the kernel to reclaim
>   the memory which is used for caching of directory and inode objects.
>
> At the default value of vfs_cache_pressure=100 the kernel will attempt
>   to reclaim dentries and inodes at a "fair" rate with respect to
>   pagecache and swapcache reclaim.  Decreasing vfs_cache_pressure causes
>   the kernel to prefer to retain dentry and inode caches. When
>   vfs_cache_pressure=0, the kernel will never reclaim dentries and
>   inodes due to memory pressure and this can easily lead to
>   out-of-memory conditions. Increasing vfs_cache_pressure beyond 100
>   causes the kernel to prefer to reclaim dentries and inodes.
>
> Increasing vfs_cache_pressure significantly beyond 100 may have
>   negative performance impact. Reclaim code needs to take various locks
>   to find freeable directory and inode objects. With
>   vfs_cache_pressure=1000, it will look for ten times more freeable
>   objects than there are.

Answer (score 2):

you can use these 2 commands to do the same job.

> Updatedb (to update the list of file and folders location in whole drive)
>
> locate / (to list all files in the whole OS, which is lightening fast as it picks them up from the Database)

Comment: Yup, I run updatedb from cron to keep the inode cache 'warm.'  It works well, take a look at your slabtop to see statistics.  Also, running `strace -c updated` can give you some insight as far as how much gets updated.

Comment: Thank you, but how does that help me improving rsync performance?edit: Ok, just read Marcin's comment, but regarding the warmness of the cache, how is it different from running a simple find /?

Comment: In some implementations, the `updatedb` shell script actually runs `find /` to get the initial file list.  On Mac OS X it still works this way.

Comment: The OP scans the filesystem multiple times per second, anyway. I don't see any advantage in scanning it even more often.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary to [seeker](https://serverfault.com/users/112550/seeker)'s answer I would like to add/highlight a few things about `vfs_cache_pressure`.

In short it

> influences the tendency the system reclaims memory for caching of VFS caches, versus pagecache and swap.

-> [doc of /proc/sys/vm/](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt)

Some important values:

- `=0`: The Kernel will *never reclaim* memory
- `=100`: Reclaim at a "fair" rate (= default)

In order to apply the changes **temporarily** adapt the value in:

```sh
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure 
15
```

For a **permanent** change (applied during reboot):

Either add a line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` or (better) create a new file in `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`. E.g.:

```sh
$ cat 10-vfs-cache-pressure.conf 
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=10
```

For me decreasing it to somewhere between `10` to `15` resulted in good performance, however this depends of course a lot on your system, amount of users and services running on it. I think there is no substitute other than playing around and carefully looking at the impact.

---

You might what to have a deeper look into [`slabtop`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/slabtop.1.html).

`slabtop` will help you investigating the consequences when changing this and related kernel parameters (`dentry` and `*inode_cache` are what you are most probably looking for -> [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4403) might also help here).